# ajax works but not displaying content?

Tags: ajax

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Chat_Box_Files/Script_Files/AJAX.js"></script>
</head>

// JavaScript Document


$(document).ready(function(){
// load index page when the page loads
Load_ajax_page("http://betaserver.bioprotege-inc.net/chat_selector/Chat_Box_Files/Script_Files/Applet_Files/Index.html");

$("#ChatMaster").click(function(){
Load_ajax_page("#");
});

});



function Load_ajax_page(url){
//before we make a ajax request we have to show the loading image
$("#Applets").html('<center>Loading... Please Wait...</center>');

//this is a jquery method to make a ajax request
$.post(url,"",function (data){
//this is the place where the data is returned by the request
//remove loading and add the data
$("#Applets").html(data);
});

}


<div id="Applets">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N278r/

here is my fiddle of it all in action, but it wont display the content from the html file, it used to idk what I have done wrong?

Comment: I think its working fine ... There is no data in your response to show.. Check this one.. http://jsfiddle.net/N278r/1/

Comment: // load index page when the page loads
    Load_ajax_page("http://betaserver.bioprotege-inc.net/chat_selector/Chat_Box_Files/Script_Fil

Comment: that line makes it load content upon page laod, which that page has an java applet and some text

Comment: CORS is not enabled on the remote server. Are you opening the html page from the same domain as betaserver.bioprotege-inc.net?

Comment: yea, it works on apache, I was using it on a text server nginx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using ASP.NET on the server. You can add  the following line to your source pages:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```